# Show text with repeated numbers (each item to show 2 times) in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, ms-office

I'm trying to show text below like

```
Number1

Number1

Number2

Number2

Number3

Number3
```

I was tried with =REPT() but no use. this is generated only into cell
and searched on online. But I don't find any solution.

Is there any formula in Excel software to show text two times with a number?
Please, anyone, help me.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
="Number" & ROUNDUP(ROW(1:1)/2,0)
```